# How to display dynamic content in a table without spacing?

Tags: php, css

I have some names that are pulled from a MySQL database that I want to display on an html page. The number of names and length of the names varies but they must all fit into a fixed width on the page.

So far I have them all displaying within a table and I am creating a new row whenever five names are displayed (See attached image showing dummy names). This isn't too bad but it bugs me that the names are all aligning themselves on the left of each table column. How can I display the names close together without the fixed spacing and create a new row each time 5 or even 6 names are displayed.

[image: dummy names in a table / new row everytime five <td> are created.]

Here's a piece of my code that shows how I am creating this.

```
$t=0;
echo "<td><span class=\"label label-default\" id=\"tag\">$uname</span> </td>";
//Control width of table 
$t++;

if ($t=='5'){
echo '</tr><tr>';
$t=0;
}



        }//End foreach loop
echo '</tr></tbody></table>
```

Comment: you got typo here: `</span `. attribute `id` is unique identifier of element. in you code all of td-s have the same id.

Comment: share the css pls

Comment: If you want to arrange them without spacing, get rid of the table... `span`s will be laid out one right after another and they will break to new line as needed...

Comment: Spans sounds good. Will they create a new line when they reach the width of the <div> column?

Comment: I just putting each name in a <span>. Whilst the spacing is good they all appear on one single line. How do I set the width of the span line or number of names per line? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Option 1** - parent: `text-align:center;` child: `display: inline-block;`

```css
.some-container {
  text-align: center;
}
.some-container span {
  display: inline-block;
}

/* below is just to style it up, so it looks closer to your picture */
.some-container {
  width: 70%;
  margin: 50px auto;
}
.some-container span {
  background-color: #aaa;
  color: white;
  padding: .5rem 1rem;
  margin: 2px;
  border-radius: 3px;
}
```

```html
<div class="some-container"><!--
  --><span>Lorem</span><!--
  --><span>ipsum</span><!--
  --><span>dolor</span><!--
  --><span>sit</span><!--
  --><span>amet</span><!--
  --><span>Lorem</span><!--
  --><span>ipsum</span><!--
  --><span>dolor</span><!--
  --><span>sit</span><!--
  --><span>sit</span><!--
  --><span>amet</span><!--
  --><span>Lorem</span><!--
  --><span>ipsum</span><!--
  --><span>dolor</span><!--
  --><span>sit</span><!--
  --><span>sit</span><!--
  --><span>amet</span><!--
  --><span>Lorem</span><!--
  --><span>ipsum</span><!--
  --><span>dolor</span><!--
  --><span>sit</span><!--
  --><span>sit</span><!--
  --><span>amet</span><!--
  --><span>Lorem</span><!--
  --><span>ipsum</span><!--
  --><span>dolor</span><!--
  --><span>sit</span><!--
  --><span>sit</span><!--
  --><span>amet</span><!--
  --><span>Lorem</span><!--
  --><span>ipsum</span><!--
  --><span>dolor</span><!--
  --><span>sit</span><!--
--></div>
```

**Option 2** - `flexbox` (preferred)

```css
.some-container {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  justify-content: center;
}

/* below is just to style it up, so it looks closer to your picture */
.some-container {
  width: 70%;
  margin: 50px auto;
}
.some-container span {
  background-color: #aaa;
  color: white;
  padding: .5rem 1rem;
  margin: 2px;
  border-radius: 3px;
}
```

```html
<div class="some-container">
  <span>Lorem</span>
  <span>ipsum</span>
  <span>dolor</span>
  <span>sit</span>
  <span>amet</span>
  <span>Lorem</span>
  <span>ipsum</span>
  <span>dolor</span>
  <span>sit</span>
  <span>amet</span>
  <span>Lorem</span>
  <span>ipsum</span>
  <span>dolor</span>
  <span>sit</span>
  <span>amet</span>
  <span>Lorem</span>
  <span>ipsum</span>
  <span>dolor</span>
  <span>sit</span>
  <span>amet</span>
  <span>Lorem</span>
  <span>ipsum</span>
  <span>dolor</span>
  <span>sit</span>
  <span>amet</span>
  <span>Lorem</span>
  <span>ipsum</span>
  <span>dolor</span>
  <span>sit</span>
  <span>amet</span>
  <span>Lorem</span>
  <span>ipsum</span>
  <span>dolor</span>
  <span>sit</span>
  <span>amet</span>
</div>
```

Why is 2 better than 1: You will notice I had to wrap all whitespace (new lines, tabs and indent spaces) in `html` comments for the first solution to display properly. That's because browsers consider `inline-block`s as *big letters*. And they reduce all whitespace between the elements to one single space which gets rendered between your boxes (unless you don't comment them, as I did). Solution 2 doesn't require this.
Also, `flexbox` has more positioning features available (i.e. vertical centering, if you provide a height for parent; or evenly distribute free space on each row, much like a justified paragraph).

---

Did I say you should definitely drop the `<table>` idea? That's for tabular data only (think sorting, pagination). Don't use it for layout. Ever.

Comment: That is a brilliant answer, many thanks. I went with option two as you suggested. I forgot to mention I am using a bootstrap 3 framework which requires a particular class for flexbox to work with Bootstrap. <div class="d-flex p-2">I'm a flexbox container!</div>. Worked perfectly.

Answer (score 0):

If it has to be in a table, just make all the `span` elements block elements, using this CSS:

```
td > span {
  display: block;
}
```

That way they all get stretched to the width of their parent elements (the cells), leaving no spaces (except the cell borders)

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/ZLmjvy